# Mispronunciation in Dhikr and Kufr

Tags: kufr, dhikr, mistake

I was doing Dhikr and I was saying Allahu Akbar and I put more emphasis on the L’s in in Allahu and not the A. I didn’t think anything of it until I saw someone ask a question about mispronunciation in Dhikr and if mispronunciation in Dhikr makes you Kufr. Does my mispronunciation make me a kufr?

Comment: Kufr mean you close yourself from the truth (Islam). So no it's not kufr unless you change the meaning of the words, and even if you did that's still recorded as a mistake(unintentional) and therefore an exemption. And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

Actions are by intentions, so what you have done may not be kufr. **evidence:** Riyadh as-saliheen 1.

But to be on the safe side you can:

Recite the dua:

> Allahumma ini a'oudho un ushrika bika wa 'alamu wa astaghfiruka Lima la 'alamu ( O Allah! I seek refuge you that we associate partners with you knowingly and we seek forgiveness for what we do unknowingly.) In Al Adab Al Mufrad, This dua is classified as saheeh.

Recite it sincerely (I.e knowing its meaning and knowing that you are gonna get what is asked in this dua) and In Shaa Allah, this will be sufficient for you.

Comment: Please consider supporting your claims by evidences.